# Speedup PyQt def?

Tags: python, pyqt5

My PyQt app is slow. What have i do to speedup this def:

```
def paint(self):
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        c = []
        for j in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            c.append(self.tableWidget.item(j, i).text())

        if "X" not in c:
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                self.tableWidget.item(j, i).setBackground(
                    QtGui.QColor(125, 125, 125))
        else:
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                self.tableWidget.item(j, i).setBackground(
                    QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 251))
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over the rows twice?

Comment: @KlausD the first iteration is to find the match, the second to set the colors, which seem common to *all* items. It certainly is not optimal, as a break would be better, or at least store the items in a list instead of fetching them twice.

Comment: @endyaris that doesn't look like a paint function, what calls that and how often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to implement that logic through a delegate:

```py
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        column = index.column()
        model = index.model()
        found = False
        for row in range(model.columnCount()):
            if model.index(row, column).data() == "X":
                found = True
                break
        option.backgroundBrush = (
            QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 251) if found else QtGui.QColor(125, 125, 125)
        )
```

```
delegate = Delegate(self.tableWidget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: This works like a charm but i dont understand it. Give me a source to find out please.